# NestedTree Symfony2 Gedmo annotation show list with Tree

Tags: symfony

i have a simple probleme but i dont know how to fix it, 
 Here we go,

I already have a table that contains all menu registred on database, like this

[image]

http://snapplr.com/snap/hbch

But, the entity with title A is parent of entity B, so all i want to do now is to tree my list as dependencies with parent and children Tree Gedmo annotation.

this is my index.html.twig page

```
{% block tbody %}
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entity.title|title }}</td>
            <td>{% if entity.type == 'javascript:void(0)' %}
                    Groupe
                    {% else %}
                    {{ entity.type|title }}
            {% endif %}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.value|title }}</td>
            <td>
                {% render(controller('MenuBundle:Backend/MenuExtends:createDelete', {'id' : entity.id, 'menu' : id})) %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok 
here my entity

```html
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Menu", inversedBy="extends")
     */
    private $menu;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\TreePathSource
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(name="submenu_left", type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(name="submenu_root", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $root;
    
    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(name="submenu_level", type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(name="submenu_right", type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MenuExtends", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MenuExtends", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;
```

what i want to do is : 
if an entity have a children, in the same line , open x lines for the x children ...